# window.pageYOffset before and after onscroll event javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple script for a "disappearing" navbar that's supposed to disappear on scroll down and appear again on scroll up.

The script is not mine, but I don't understand how this works if I'm comparing two variables that apparently have the exact same value since the `window.pageYOffset` returns the number of pixels of the document that has been scrolled from the top. The only difference is that one variable is in the global scope and the second one isn't.

The variable `currentScrollPos` is inside the function for the 'onscroll' event,  so I'm guessing the `previousScrollPos` stores the number of pixels on the Y position first, then the other variable because it's in the global scope and that's why inside the function I can check if previous is greater than currentScrollPos...?  Is this correct?

And if I end the function saying that `previousScrollPos = currentScrollPos` (which makes the nav bar appear again at scroll up), how does it still make the condition be possible in the scroll down?

This is probably a dumb question but I'm just not getting it..  Help please

JS

```
const header = document.querySelector("header");
let previousScrollPos = window.pageYOffset; 
//console.log({previousScrollPos})

window.onscroll = function(){
    let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    //console.log({previousScrollPos})
    //console.log({currentScrollPos})

    previousScrollPos > currentScrollPos ?
      header.classList.remove("scroll") : header.classList.add("scroll") 

    previousScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

CSS

```
header{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:7rem;
    background-color:var(--main-color);
    z-index:1;
    transition:.5s;
}
header.scroll{
    position:fixed;
    top:-7rem;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:7rem;
    background-color:var(--main-color);
    z-index:1;
    transition:.5s;
}
```

Comment: Yeah your analysis is correct. As on scroll the currentScrollPos value changes .Comparing to the previousValue which is saved globally we know the scrolling is moving up or down. Then the CSS class will help to add or remove navbar.

Answer (score 0):

`previousScrollPos` contains the value of `window.pageYOffset` at the last 'scroll' event.

`currentScrollPos` contains the value of `window.pageYOffset` at the current 'scroll' event.

These will always be different when the code that shows/hides the menu is evaluated, as `currentScrollPos` is set on every 'scroll' event.

This little test program shows the scrolling information, which should help you understand what is going on.

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');
let previousScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function() {
  let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  let showStr = 'previousScrollPos: ' + previousScrollPos + '\n' +
    'currentScrollPos: ' + currentScrollPos + '\n';

  showStr += previousScrollPos > currentScrollPos ?
    'scroll up' : 'scroll down';

  result.innerHTML = showStr;

  previousScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 60rem;
  width: 90%;
}

#result {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 80px;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Test pageYOffset</h1>
  <p>Scroll the page up and down.</p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let lastScrollY = window.pageYOffset;
let scroll = null;

window.onscroll = function() {
  const scrollY = window.pageYOffset; 
  const direction = scrollY > lastScrollY ? "down" : "up";

  if (direction !== scroll) {
    scroll==direction
  }

  lastScrollY = scrollY > 0 ? scrollY : 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! It would be helpful if you added text explaining and walking through what the code accomplishes.

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.

Comment: I also think it's meant to be `scroll = direction` with one `=` sign.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).